# Expectations in markov chain model with stopping time

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

In an institute, a lab rat is used for experimentation of a certain medication.
Each evening, there are two treatment options: applying 1 ml of the medication or not. The
response of the rat to the applied treatment is checked in the evening of the next day. If the
response of the rat to the treatment is positive then the same treatment is applied, otherwise
the treatment is switched.
If the medication is not applied, the response is positive with probability 0.38, negative
with probability 0.6 and the rat dies with probability 0.02. If 1 ml of the medication is
applied, the response is positive with probability 0.65, negative with probability 0.3 and the
rat dies with probability 0.05.
(a) Model the process as a Markov chain and find the one step transition probability matrix.

(b) If the medication was not applied on Monday evening, what is the probability that the
treatment will be applied on Thursday evening?

(c) The lab rat was given the medication on Sunday evening. The rat will be transferred to
another testing facility on next Sunday morning (if it still lives). An employee is tasked with
bringing enough supplies of the medication until transfer. What is the expected amount of
medication that should be brought?

I need help for part b) and c)

Answer (score 1):

For part a) $P=\begin{bmatrix}
 0.65&0.3  &0.05 \\ 
 0.6&0.38  & 0.02\\ 
 0&0  &1 
\end{bmatrix}$

I need help for part b) and c)

Comment: In the second line, you need to switch the places of $0.38$ and $0.6$ for the matrix to be correct.

Comment: For b) it is Thursday not Tuesday. So Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday.

Comment: Oh thanks something confused me in the question i got it now what it meant by switching the treatment thanks